# Way to get localized label name from PackageManager

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I am using `PackageManager.getApplicationLabel(ApplicationInfo)` to get the application name. But this name may change according to the device locale configuration and application resource string.

So I wonder if there is any convenient way to get a specified localized label (or return null if not exist)? Such as `PackageManager.getApplicationLabel(ApplicationInfo info, Locale prefereLocale)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, lets describe order of actions to obtain the label:

1. Obtain `ApplicationInfo` (application info has [`public int labelRes`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#labelRes) - resource id of the label);
2. Obtain application resources to retrieve `labelRes` from it - using [getResourcesForApplication()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication%28java.lang.String%29);
3. Set necessary locale to obtained `Resources` and retrieve string `labelRes` (please note, that I haven't mentioned [nonLocalizedLabel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageItemInfo.html#nonLocalizedLabel) which should be checked before doing all above items);

The code itself is pretty simple (e.g. code from activity class):

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        ApplicationInfo galleryInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("com.android.gallery3d", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        if (null != galleryInfo) {
            final String label = String.valueOf(pm.getApplicationLabel(galleryInfo));

            Log.w(TAG, "Current app label is " + label);

            final Configuration config = new Configuration();

            config.locale = new Locale("ru");

            final Resources galleryRes = pm.getResourcesForApplication("com.android.gallery3d");

            galleryRes.updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            final String localizedLabel = galleryRes.getString(galleryInfo.labelRes);

            Log.w(TAG, "Localized app label is " + localizedLabel);
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to obtain app info!");
    }
```

Produces the following output (second string label is in Russian locale which I set from code - 'ru'):

```
08-16 19:23:04.425: WARN/MyActivity(29122): Current app label is Gallery
08-16 19:23:04.425: WARN/MyActivity(29122): Localized app label is Галерея
```